# How to model shipment size constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, constraint

I am working on an LP problem where I have to model a constraint as:

"The total number of units of product A and B should be shipped in multiples of $1200$"

e.g. $700\text{(product A)} + 500\text{(product B)} = 1200\times1 = 1200$
or

$1800\text{(product A)} + 600\text{(product B)} = 1200\times2 = 2400$
or

$2000\text{(product A)} + 1600\text{(product B)} = 1200\times3 = 3600$

like that maximum shipment should be $6000$ units $(1200\times5)$, or I can say in other words as I can only ship $5$ batches of $1200$ units each.

Can somebody please help me to write such a constraint in algebraic form: 
$Xa + Xb = $?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x_p$ denotes the quantity of product $p\in P$ that is shipped :
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\in P}x_p &= 1200 k \\
k &\in \mathbb{N} \\
x_p &\in \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}

Comment: @TheSimpliFire : just out of curiosity, why is better to write equations with \begin{align}, rather than with '$$' symbols ?

Comment: Well because it aligns equations together :) (note that $$ and \\ newline do not achieve this as there is no command to align $=$ and $\in$ in this case)